# Preprocessing layers with seed not producing the same data augmentation for images and masks

Tags: tensorflow, data-augmentation, data-preprocessing, image-masking

I'm trying to create a simple preprocessing augmentation layer, following this Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation#download_the_oxford-iiit_pets_dataset). I created this 'simple' example that shows the problem I'm having.

Even though I'm initializing the augmentation class with a seed, operations applied to the images, and the corresponding masks are not always equal.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: tf v2.10.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage
import rasterio as rio

def normalize(array: np.ndarray):
    """ normalise image to give a meaningful output """
    array_min, array_max = array.min(), array.max()
    return (array - array_min) / (array_max - array_min)

# field
im = rio.open('penguins.tif')
fields = np.zeros((1,im.shape[0],im.shape[1],3))
fields[0,:,:,0] = normalize(im.read(1))
fields[0,:,:,1] = normalize(im.read(2))
fields[0,:,:,2] = normalize(im.read(3))

# mask is a simple contour
masks = skimage.color.rgb2gray(skimage.filters.sobel(fields[0]))
masks = np.expand_dims(masks, [0,3])
```

In this case, the dataset is only one image, we can use this function to visualize the field and the mask.

```
def show(field:np.ndarray, mask:np.ndarray): 
    """Show the field and corresponding mask."""
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    ax1.imshow(field[:,:,:3])
    ax2.imshow(mask,cmap='binary')    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

show(fields[0], masks[0])
```

[image: image and field]

Alright, now I used the example from the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation#download_the_oxford-iiit_pets_dataset) that will randomly flip (horizontal) the image and the mask.

```
class Augment(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, seed=42):
        super().__init__()
        # both use the same seed, so they'll make the same random changes.
        self.augment_inputs = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", seed=seed)
        self.augment_labels = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", seed=seed)

    def call(self, inputs, labels):
        inputs = self.augment_inputs(inputs)
        labels = self.augment_labels(labels)
        return inputs, labels
```

Now if I run the following multiple times, I will eventually get opposite flip on the field and mask.

```
# Create a tf.datasets
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((fields, masks))

ds2 = ds.map(Augment())

for f,m in ds2.take(1):
    show(f, m)
```

[image: different processing to image and mask]

I would expect the image and its mask to be flip the same way since I set the seed in the `Augment` class as suggested in the Tensorflow tutorial.

Comment: you should file this as a bug. Even if you fix the problem, given the seed is fixed, won't the augment be all same?. The seed should be from a random generator. Don't think the tutorial is right. I would not augment labels and image separately with a seed given the problems. I would change the Augment function to concat the image and labels along the channel axis  and form a single array and do augmentation of a single array. Then recover the image and label back.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a simple way of fixing the problem. I commented back on this issue since it seems to be related (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35090#issuecomment-1345470684), hopefully they re-open it.

Comment: cool. if you find any issues with the concat method, you can post here, ill try to answer it.

Comment: I'm unsure how to perform a last step.. So my dataset is a : `<TensorSliceDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(256, 256, 5), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)>`. I can apply the `Augment()` layer, but eventually, I have to split back the images, and the masks. I tried to use `tf.slice` inside the `Augment()` class, but even if I return `images, labels` I received one `<MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(256, 256, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>` that is not batch properly for training.

Comment: your images have 4 channels?

Comment: Yes, sorry, in my real problem images are RGBA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250357/discussion-between-philippe-miron-and-v-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Augmentation can be done on the concatenated `image` and `mask` along the channel axis to form a single array and then recover the `image` and `label` back, which is shown below:

```
class Augment(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # both use the same seed, so they'll make the same random changes.
        self.augment_inputs = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.3)


    def call(self, inputs, labels):
        
        output = self.augment_inputs(tf.concat([inputs, labels], -1) )
        
        inputs = output[:,:,0:4]
        labels = output[:,:,4:]

        return inputs, labels
```

Comment: So the mask just ends up as an additional channel? Smart.
But is this really the best practice?